# Patching hole in TMS?

Tags: gdal2tiles, tile-map-service

I created a large TMS (couple of gigs) using gdal2tiles, just to discover in the end that there was a hole (a gap) in the images, similar to the example bellow.

[image: TMS with hole]

Since then I've obtained the missing image and I'd like to recreate the TMS. Is there a way to just patch the hole in the TMS folder structure? Or do I have to generate the entire thing again?

*Update:* The white area in the TMS is not a missing tile. I had a missing image when I created the tiles. So my tiles have a white box in them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the missing tiles were, for whatever reason, not created at all and there is not just a problem displaying them:

You can try to run the same command you used in the first place with the additional parameter *-e* or *--resume*

Using this option, all tiles which are already there are not created again and it is a lot faster than creating everything from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not missing tiles. I had a missing image when I created the tiles. So I have tiles with a white square in them.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. Unfortunately, I also don't have a good solution right now for this issue. But I will think about it and if I find a solution, I will update my answer.